# How to check applied policies and/or the user limits on a subscription

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm using "MSDN Platforms" and "Developer Program Benefit" subscriptions. 
I'm unable to access to create resource groups and services in certain locations on a selected subscription either through azure portal or Azure Powershell. Sometimes getting exceptions on quota limits.

How do I check applied policies and/or the user limits on a subscription?

Asking because of the subscription limitations I got error message in the following scenario

1. Created availability set in southindia location

[image: Created availability set in southindia location]

[image]

2. Trying to deploy a VM in the same location.

Comment: Do you mean you could create services in some location? If you could not create service in all location, you need check your user's role firstly, I suggest you should give your user owner role.

Comment: Thank you. Please go through update scenario. Will it get solved by support request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I check applied policies and/or the user limits on a
>   subscription?

You could check it on Azure Portal. `<your subscription>-->Usage + quotas`.

[image]

If you reach your subscription limit, you could create a ticket to raise the limit, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/resource-manager-core-quotas-request).

Also, you need check your user's role, if you want to create resources in Azure, I suggest you select `Owner` or `Contributor` role. Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#assign-application-to-role).

Note: In this link I provide, the application name is your user name.